# Looping in the rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Ok so i have this loop in my routes.rb file

```
[:animals, :humans].each do |app|
  resources app, controller => "mammals", type: app.to_s do
    member do
      post :deny
    end

    collection do
      get :wait, :state => 'wait', :action => 'index'
    end
  end
end
```

but i get this error wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

```
/Users/trace/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@sss/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:651:in `controller'
/Users/trace/Sites/sss/config/routes.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/trace/Sites/sss/config/routes.rb:30:in `each'
```

but i use loops in other portions of routes.rb and all is good

any ideas on what is going on...maybe a syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks suspicious:

`resources app, controller => "mammals", type: app.to_s do`

How about:

```
resources app, controller: "mammals", type: app.to_s do
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the colon on controller.

```
  resources app, controller => "mammals", type: app.to_s do
```

should be

```
  resources app, :controller => "mammals", type: app.to_s do
```